# Where to commit small, miscellaneous changes

Tags: git, branching

Let's assume that I am working on a small project that uses feature branches to organize tasks. For example, `feature/login` would be for working on the login functionality and `feature/create-new-post` would be for adding functionality to allow users to create new posts. When a feature branch comes to a relatively stable stopping place, it gets merged into `development` which is an up-to-date-ish version of the codebase.

Now let's say I find a typo in a comment in some file. This file is quite generic and doesn't really fit into one particular feature branch. If I am working away in `feature/login` when I discover this, what branch should I commit this fix to? I feel that it would be wrong to commit to `feature/login` because the typo is completely unrelated to login functionality. It also feels wrong just to commit directly to my development branch because that isn't usually the process.

Note - this is (pretty much) a hypothetical, I'm wondering what the cleanest solution in general would be.

Comment: I suspect there's no right answer to this. My gut feeling is that I'd commit it straight to `development`. But someone else may well offer a compelling argument for a different approach, so I reserve the right to totally change my mind.

Comment: I'd say straight to development or along a feature branch, as long as it's a very minor change. Especially if you adhere to the [boy scout rule](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/97-things-every/9780596809515/ch08.html) you'll accept that minor changes are allowed if they improve the codebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen a number of different approaches:

**Submit with feature**

Although it doesn't belong in the feature code per se, it is simply added to the feature branch *as long as the risk is low*.

**Submit on separate branch**

For larger or more riskier changes, it may be prudent to have a separate branch.

**Submit on child branch**

Admittedly quite rare, but a change might be triaged and the change made on a child branch with a view to merging this into a later feature branch.

---

For trivial changes, it can be tempting simply to merge this into development but it is worth at least discussing this with peers first to set the ground rules. I've seen many a trivial change break builds and the fall out is usually more painful than simply putting it into a branch.

Comment: Good answer, thanks for discussing multiple different avenues to take